# Reversing doubly linked list, but infinite loop

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have tried reversing the doubly linked list, and this is my code for reverse! why am I going to infinity loop?

```
public void reverselist() {
    
    Doubly_node temp = head;
    
    while(temp.next != null) {
        
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    
    
    
    while(temp.prev != null) {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp= temp.prev;
    }
    
}
```

[enter link description here](https://notepad.pw/n2c263oe)

Comment: what is Doubly_node? Incomplete codes for a diagnose.

Comment: How did you setup ur list? I do not see how this can end up in an infinite loop unless you managed to inject a loop into your list itself. Your code should successfully loop from head to tail and then back from tail to head and then terminate. It wont reverse anything, but it should not result in an infinite loop. In particular, it will print all the lists data in reverse order - so you managed to do that.

Comment: change while(temp.prev != null) to while(temp != head) {

Comment: 1)  The above code doesn't reverse the list.  It traverses it backwards.  2)  If you are getting an infinite loop from the above code, then the root cause is not in *that* code.  It is somewhere else; e.g. some code that creates or modifies the list.

Comment: i have added my code in the link please check guys

Answer (score 0):

you want to just traverse or reverse doubly linked list?
check below

```
    {
        Doubly_node curr = head;
        Doubly_node t = null;

        while (curr != null) {
            t = curr.prev;
            curr.prev = curr.next;
            curr.next = t;
            curr = curr.prev;
        }
        if (t != null) {
            head = t.prev;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Comment: bro my traversal was done in the code
   while(temp.next != null) {
        
        temp = temp.next;
    }

Comment: Hello @AbhishekSah check my comment - change while(temp.prev != null) to while(temp != head)   and i meant you just want to reverse traverse list & print Or you want to reverse list completely in mapping

Comment: i am still getting infinite loop

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4592066/rahul-sawant if write (temp != head) i wont get my 1st node!!